# Запятая после однако и вот

Tags: пунктуация

"Однако вот что замечательно:..." Ставится ли запятая после однако и вот? Почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Однако = но, это союз, после него нет запятой

Вот что- сочетание указательной частицы ВОТ  с вопросительно-относительным местоимением и наречием является слитным,запятой не разделяется.

Answer (score 0):

После "однако" в начале предложения запятая обычно не ставится, оно считается союзом. Хотя в каком-то контексте, думаю, можно посчитать и вводным, даже в начале фразы.

Перед "что" запятая не нужна,предшествуюшая часть не относится к самостоятельному предложению, "вот" - усилительно-указательная частица.